# Example of a Borel measure, which is not Borel-regular

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, geometric-measure-theory

I have asked a question to find four types of outer measures [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586731/inclusions-for-certain-types-of-measures/), and I could find three of the four examples.

We call an outer measure $\mu: \mathcal P(\mathbb R^n) \to [0, \infty]$ **Borel**, if every Borel set $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ is $\mu$-measurable. We say, that an outer measure $\mu: \mathcal P(\mathbb R^n) \to [0, \infty]$ is **Borel-regular**, if $\mu$ is Borel and for any subset $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ there is a Borel set $B \supset A$, such that $\mu(A) = \mu(B)$.

I would like to give an example of a Borel measure, which is not Borel-regular. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a set $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not Borel. For every $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, let
$$
\mu(X) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if } X\subset C; \\
\infty & \text{if } X\not\subset C. \\
\end{cases}
$$
This is a measure on the entire $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In particular, all Borel sets are measuable.

For every Borel set $B\supset C$ we have
$\mu(B)=\infty> 0=\mu(C)$, so $\mu$ is not Borel-regular.

Comment: Thanks for this example! This is exactly what I was looking for. You mentioned that $C \subset \mathbb R^n$ is not Borel. Is there an easy way to construct a non-Borel set in $\mathbb R^n$? I know the example of the Vitali set, a non-Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$. Is there a similar way to construct a non-Borel subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Thanks for the points.. (Sorry, I cannot know better than Vitali.)

Comment: Does every Borel set $B$ contain $C$? (I know this is an old question but here's hoping someone will answer)