# Help proving a measure is not Borel regular.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600673/example-of-a-borel-measure-which-is-not-borel-regular) an example of a measure that is not Borel regular was given. However, I do not understand why this measure would not be Borel regular.

I should think that what is said only works for Borel sets which contain the given set $C$. But what about Borel sets which do not? Or does every Borel set contain $C$? How would we prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borel regularity of $\mu$ requires that for *every* $\mu$-measurable set $A$, there *exists* a Borel set $B$ containing $A$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$. In the example, the set $C$ is $\mu$-measurable but any Borel set containing $C$ has strictly larger measure than $C$ itself.